# Import and Export file with iTunes from an IOS app

Tags: ios, swift, import

I work with Xcode 7 and Swift 2 for create an IOS app.
I want my users to import file in my application and recover the IOS device by connecting to iTunes.
I would have to can access the file from my code ...
Here is a sample application that offers this principle (VLC, Excel ...).
And here's a screen for you to understand! ;)
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a documentation: [Core Services Layer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html)

> To enable file sharing for your app, do the following:
>
> 1. Add the UIFileSharingEnabled key to your app’s Info.plist file, and set the value of the key to YES.
> 2. Put whatever files you want to share in your app’s Documents directory.
> 3. When the device is plugged into the user’s computer, iTunes displays a File Sharing section in the Apps tab of the selected device.
> 4. The user can add files to this directory or move files to the desktop.

After enabling File Sharing, you could just manipulating the `Documents` directory.

You could also use a tutorial like this one:

[iTunes Tutorial for iOS: How To Integrate iTunes File Sharing With Your iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app)